# Problem installing tensorflow and tf-nightly

Tags: python, tensorflow

So after installing tensorflow, I installed tf-nightly using `pip install tf-nightly`. After the installation I get error messages like:

`tf-nightly 2.5.0.dev20210204 requires grpcio~=1.34.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.33.2 which is incompatible.`

`tensorflow 2.4.1 requires grpcio~=1.32.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.33.2 which is incompatible.`

Now how do I rectify this issue where both require different versions of `grpcio`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue has been resolved. Take a look at similar issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45785